# Passing a file into a function

Tags: c++, function, ifstream

I'm trying to create a program that passes a file to a function. The function is supposed to detect how many lines are in my file. I don't think I'm passing the file correctly into my function, I've tried several different ways.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define die(errmsg) {cerr << errmsg << endl; exit(1);} 
using namespace std;

int num_of_lines(ifstream file)
{
    int cnt3;
    string str;

    while(getline(file, str))cnt3++;

    return(cnt3);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int num_of_lines(ifstream file);

    string file;
    file = argv[1];

    if(argc == 1)die("usage: mywc your_file"); //for some reason not working

    ifstream ifs;

    ifs.open(file);

    if(ifs.is_open())
    {
        int a;
        cout << "File was opened\n";

        a = num_of_lines(file);

        cout <<"Lines: " << a << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr <<"Could not open: " << file << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    ifs.close();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: This might sound like nit-picking, and you may already realize this, but you're not really passing a file to a function. You have an object that represents the input stream, so you're passing an `ifstream` into your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems with the function.  First, you should pass the stream by reference.  Second, you just forgot to initialise your counter.

```
int num_of_lines( ifstream &file )
{
    int cnt3 = 0;
    string str;
    while( getline(file, str) ) cnt3++;
    return cnt3;
}
```

The other thing is you're passing `file` to it (which is a string) instead of `ifs`.  Change the call to:

```
a = num_of_lines( ifs );
```